# ConTeXt mkIV and XML: how do you define a self-closing tag with no content to pass?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, xml, tei

I am using TEI Lite, and trying to typeset with ConTeXt. TEI Lite defines `<divGen type='toc' />` to signal the Table of Contents, which in ConTeXt is `\completecontents`

Now I am trying this:

```
\startxmlsetups xml:divGen[@type='toc']
                \completecontents
\stopxmlsetups
```

but it's not working.

How do I map this self-closing tag to the ConTeXt Table of Contents command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not put the XML path selector in the setup name: the `\startxmlsetups` ... `\stopxmlsetups` is just defining a command, not actually selecting items from the XML file.

It is `\xmlsetsetup` that does the XML object selection.

I am not a heavy user of ConTeXt's xml support myself, but I think you need something like this:

```
\xmlsetsetup{}{xml:divGen[@type='toc']}{xml:divgen:toc}
\startxmlsetups xml:divgen:toc
     \completecontents
\stopxmlsetups
```

Comment: Probably needs to be `\completecontent` as per https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/completecontent ...